# Shrink Or Expand Margins With Window Resize

Tags: layout, margin, css

Here's the code I've been fiddling with: http://jsfiddle.net/denWG/3/

First, you'll need to expand the right column that contains the HTML and CSS. Notice how the grey container expands and contracts to 90% of the available width.

```
#container
{
    width: 90%;

    margin: 16px auto;
    /* More rules... */
}
```

Ideally, I want the green box to start on the right wall of the container. As the window shrinks, it pushes the right border closer to the left border. I want the green box to have this behavior. As the window shrinks, I want the right border to push the green box towards the red box.

Both boxes are `display: inline-block;`.

Initially, I thought of adding `margin-right: some%;` to the red box, but that didn't work like I thought it would.

Eventually, I wanted to have a grid of red and green boxes. Am I approaching this correctly? Any advice? Thanks a million!

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/denWG/4/

Comment: I noticed you also added `min-width: 280px`. I've run into that property before, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Could you explain that? Or point me to an article or something? Thank. You.

Comment: It means that if you resize(decrease) any element, it will not become smaller than the provided `min-width`. It will just indicate that this element can have this minimum possible width. check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the following css:

```
    #container {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 16px auto;
        padding: 16px;
        position:relative;  /* added */
        border: solid 1px #333;
        background-color: #eee;
        min-width: 280px;
    }

    #greenBox {
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        position:absolute;  /* added */
        top:16px;
        right:16px;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denWG/4/)**